# function inside functions in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

How do I write this in coffee script?

```
function setUpDialogForms() {
    setUpListForm();
    setUpUpdateForm();
}
```

I have tried

```
setUpDialogForms -> setUpListForm(); setUpUpdateForm()
```

Comment: You've got already correct answer here, but this link might be useful in such situations. Here you go: http://js2coffee.org

Answer (score 4):

Provided the `setUpListForm` and `setUpUpdateForm` functions are defined somewhere, you can use:

```
setUpDialogForms = ->
  setUpListForm()
  setUpUpdateForm()

setUpDialogForms()
```

Comment: This is the more coffeescript-ish answer, e.g. no () for function params, and not forcing the null return.

Answer (score 1):

Found it out.

```
setUpDialogForms = () -> 
    setUpListForm() 
    setUpUpdateForm()
    return
```

Which returns

```
var setUpDialogForms;

setUpDialogForms = function() {
  setUpListForm();
  setUpUpdateForm();
};
```